# Java analogue clock

Tags: java, swing, time, graphics, clock

I am trying to implement a simple analogue clock in java. My clock successfully displays the time when I first run the program, however upon opening the time remains the same and none of the drawing updates and it freezes. I don't understand why it is not working and I have looked through the forum trying to find someone with a similar problem and cannot. If anyone can find where I am going wrong I would greatly appreciate it, thanks

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing. JPanel;

public class ClockFace extends JPanel {

Date date = new Date();

private BufferedImage clockFace;

public ClockFace() {

    this.init();
    this.startClock();

}

private void init() {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Clock");
    window.setContentPane(this);

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));

    window.pack();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

//Draws the image to the ClockFace panel
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D twoD = (Graphics2D) g;
    twoD.drawImage(clockFace, 0, 0, null);

}

public void startClock() {

    while(true) {

        int seconds = date.getSeconds();
        int minutes = date.getMinutes();
        int hours = date.getHours();

        clockFace = new BufferedImage(600,600,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D twoD = clockFace.createGraphics();
        twoD.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        twoD.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
        twoD.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        twoD.translate(300,300);

        //Drawing the hour markers
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++) {

            twoD.drawLine(0, -260, 0, -300);
            twoD.rotate(Math.PI/6);

        }

        twoD.rotate(seconds*Math.PI/30);
        twoD.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -290);

        twoD.rotate(2*Math.PI-seconds*Math.PI/30);
        twoD.rotate(minutes*Math.PI/30);
        twoD.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        twoD.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -250);

        twoD.rotate(2*Math.PI-minutes*Math.PI/30);
        twoD.rotate(hours*Math.PI/6);
        twoD.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
        twoD.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -200);

        repaint();

        //Pausing until the next "tick"
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: The `get` methods of `Date` are deprecated. Instead I recommend you use `LocalTime`, one of the classes from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. Also, are you ever changing the value of `date`? [Link: Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from processing any new input events or processing any new paint events

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

So instead of...

```
public void startClock() {
    while(true) {
       //...
    }
}
```

You should be using something more like...

```
public void startClock() {
    Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //... Update time and schedule repaint
        }
    }
}
```

See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

You will also find that this...

```
//Draws the image to the ClockFace panel
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D twoD = (Graphics2D) g;
    twoD.drawImage(clockFace, 0, 0, null);

}
```

Gives you issues (paint artefacts).  It should be..

```
//Draws the image to the ClockFace panel
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D twoD = (Graphics2D) g;
    twoD.drawImage(clockFace, 0, 0, null);

}
```

## Updated...

There's been (too) much discussion over weather the core issue is to do with the potential blocking of the Event Dispatching Thread or the non-mutable nature of the `Date` class.

The fact is, is probably both.

`java.util.Date` is a snapshot of a point in time (when it's created), it doesn't change and is not updated.  So, based on your example, you'd have to update the `date` instance on each iteration of the loop.

A better solution would probably be to use `java.time.LocalTime`, apart from been more up-to-date, it's generally simpler to use (IMHO)

For example...

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalField;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ClockFace());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ClockFace extends JPanel {

        public ClockFace() {
            this.startClock();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
            int seconds = now.getSecond();
            int minutes = now.getMinute();
            int hours = now.getHour();

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.translate(300, 300);

            //Drawing the hour markers
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

                g2d.drawLine(0, -260, 0, -300);
                g2d.rotate(Math.PI / 6);

            }

            g2d.rotate(seconds * Math.PI / 30);
            g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -290);

            g2d.rotate(2 * Math.PI - seconds * Math.PI / 30);
            g2d.rotate(minutes * Math.PI / 30);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
            g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -250);

            g2d.rotate(2 * Math.PI - minutes * Math.PI / 30);
            g2d.rotate(hours * Math.PI / 6);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
            g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -200);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void startClock() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Using `javax.swing.Timer` is the best choice for this situation.  However in general when you want to do something that takes a long time (and might block the EDT) look at `SwingWorker`, which is a general case class for background tasks less specialized than `Timer`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: He isn't actually blocking the EDT; the sleep provides enough time to let it run. But that's not the way to do it.

Comment: @markspace Just remember, `SwingWorker` has an additional overhead of synchronising (and because of the implementation places greater weight to the background thread) is a lot less regular then something like `Timer`

Comment: @laune His `ClockFace` class extends `JPanel`.  If he isn't calling its ctor on the EDT, it's wrong.  And the ctor calls the `while` loop, meaning it will block the EDT.

Comment: @laune Without further information and based on what the OP has said, it is most likely that they executing the `startClock` method within the EDT - in any case, it is a significantly safer solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I did say that `Timer` was best for this application. :-) Just wanted to point out to the OP (and any other reader) that there's other classes for avoiding blocking the EDT.

Comment: Folks, please forgive my simple-mindedless: but why does a sleep in one thread not unblock another thread?

Comment: @laune In this case, if the OP is executing the code from within the context of the EDT (and based on their description they are), then `Thread.sleep` will sleep the EDT - preventing it from processing any new paint methods - also, the `while-loop` will continue to prevent the EDT from ever been able to process the event queue, because the method never exists

Answer (score 1):

Insert the computation of `date` right after while(true).

That's not the way to write a program doing a task scheduled at time increments. It only fixes your immediate problem. See other answers.

Comment: 90% sure this is the wrong answer.  "Blocking the EDT" is the correct idea.

Comment: Well, it runs since 9:30 p.m. on my system. The sleep unblocks. Not that I'd write it like that... Timer, and all that...

Comment: @markspace there is no EDT blocking here... startclock() is not called from the EDT but from the main thread. What is wrong is that the date is never recomputed...

Comment: @laune be more precise about the *computation of date*, you should says that dates are immutable so OP needs to construct a new date object each time he needs to determine the current date/time.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Based on available code, there is no way to prove that, but, based on the description, it is a common and likely cause

Comment: @MadProgrammer well you are right (I know that this code may be called from invokeLater or alike but I doubt it is), I'm pretty sure (in that case) that the problem is first due to immutability of date.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I'd say it's cause by both :P